# R Package Doc (roxygen2) - example part - execute example

Tags: r, documentation, package, roxygen2

I'm learning how to create R packages and more specificaly documentations with `roxygen2`.

I'm using this very simple example I found somewhere online:

```
#' Add together two numbers.
#' 
#' @param x A number.
#' @param y A number.
#' @return The sum of \code{x} and \code{y}.
#' @examples
#' add(1, 1)
#' add(10, 1)
#' @export

add <- function(x, y) {
  x + y
}
```

But what I get when I run `?add` is

```
Examples

add(1, 1)  
add(10, 1)
```

While I would like to have the result of the code :

```
Examples

add(1, 1)  
2  
add(10, 1)  
11
```

Comment: `?add` will display the 'man' (manual) pages. Use `examples()` to run examples from a package. You can add the expected results to the manual pages as comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in the `@examples` section is meant to be executed as written, and in fact it is run every time you check the package with `R CMD check` ("Check Package" in R Studio). Therefore, it must not contain the output from those commands.

However, as @SymbolixAU writes, you can add comments, e.g.:

```
#' Add together two numbers.
#' 
#' @param x A number.
#' @param y A number.
#' @return The sum of \code{x} and \code{y}.
#' @examples
#' add(1, 1)
#' # 2
#'
#' add(10, 1)
#' # 11
#' @export
add <- function(x, y) {
  x + y
}
```

Or maybe rather:

```
#' Add together two numbers.
#' 
#' @param x A number.
#' @param y A number.
#' @return The sum of \code{x} and \code{y}.
#' @examples
#' add(1, 1) # returns 2
#'
#' add(10, 1) # returns 11
#' @export
add <- function(x, y) {
  x + y
}
```